# Use of ungetc and getchar function in C

Tags: c, io

I have recently started learning I/O file operations in C. And in this code I am facing an issue the while loop is not exiting even when I put nonwhite space character ' ' . Plz, tell me where I am wrong and how to exit while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a = 0;
  while ((a = (char)getchar()) != ' ');
  ungetc(a, stdin);
  printf("\n Value of A is  %c", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getchar` function returns an `int` for a reason. It can either return a character if there is one, or `EOF` to indicate the end of your input stream. So using a `char` variable to store the result is not a good idea.

Then, you should also always test for `EOF` and act accordingly if you encounter this condition.

Also, usually these streams are line buffered, so you woudn't see any input until you enter a whole line.